# function not fired from angular pipe and tap

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I am trying to call a function in my login service. Used pipe and tap. When i do `res => console.log(res)` i am getting the output. But i when i try to call a function, the call is not reaching funnction body `res => this.setSession`. Below is the entire code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from  '../api.service';
import { tap, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LoginService extends APIService{

  loginUser(logindata){
    console.log('oh yeah')
    return  this.httpClient.post(`${this.API_URL}/rest-auth/login/`, logindata)
    .pipe(tap(res => this.setSession)); 

    }

  private setSession(authResult) {
        console.log('Not coming here')

    }          

}
```

Comment: If haven't subscribed. That's why the call is not even starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call method. Use `()`:

```javascript
.pipe(
  tap(res => this.setSession())
);           // add this ---^
```

Comment: thanks @dfsq that worked. I am a newbie to typescript, was following a doc here https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/ They are calling it without brackets. It seems to have worked for many. Know why it did not work for me ? Is it a version issue ? I am using angular 7

Comment: Looks like mistake in their code, there should be `()`.